# Customizing the generated documentation of graphql playground

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to do something similar as what is implemented in this demo of the graphQL playground.

https://www.graphqlbin.com/v2/6RQ6TM

You can see when you go into the documentation here that these custom types are annotated:[image: screenshot of graphql playground demo showing custom annotations]

However, when I look around online I'm not able to find how to actually do this. I tried looking in the npm modules to see where this gets generated, but to no avail. I'd really like to be able to add extra information to this documentation. Does anybody of you have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing are just the `description` properties of those types. You can add those directly to your schema:

```
"A person is an individual person or character within the Star Wars universe."
type Person {
  id: ID!
}
```

You can utilize block strings as well if you need multiple lines:

```
"""
A person is an individual person or character
within the Star Wars universe.
"""
type Person {
  id: ID!
}
```

Or, if writing your schema programmatically, just add the appropriate property:

```
const Person = new GraphQLObject({
  name: 'Person',
  description: 'A person is an individual person or character within the Star Wars universe.',
  fields: () => {...},
})
```

Comment: Wow that's so easy too! Thank you!